# Parse xml data in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

1. Do I need to convert the response from servlet which is xml to xmlDoc for 
   parsing and retrieval of certain values?
2. If yes, then is the below code correct?  `console.log(id);` prints a function and thus a TypeError is thrown. If no, then how to do it?

```javascript
function xmlParser(xmlResponse) {
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        console.log(xmlResponse);
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlResponse, "text/xml");
        console.log(xmlDoc);
    }
    id = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    console.log(id);
    key = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("passkey")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    console.log(key);
    return format(id, key);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to convert response, because you can get `xmlDoc` directly by [`responseXML`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/xhr/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) property.

Example:

```
xmlDoc = xmlResponse.responseXML; // you'll probably need to change it because I don't know what is value of xmlResponse in your case
id = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
//and so on...
```

Comment: The content-type of the response from the server must be "text/xml" or your responseXML property will be null.

Comment: I removed the conversion code. I'm sending xml from servlet. But still get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined `

Comment: btw when do I need to convert it? when server response type is "text/html"? And what is "application/xml"?

Comment: You probably need to use `setContentType` in your servlet to set output mime type to text/xml. I don't know how your code looks like though.